# Nginx rule for Custom CMS

Tags: php, nginx

Помогите написать правило.
Frontend хорошо работает так:

```
location / {
  index index.php;

  # serve static files directly
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    access_log        off;
    expires           30d;
    break;
  }

  ### MAIN REWRITE - This will ignore directories
  if (!-d $request_filename) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php$query_string last;
  }
}
```

А вот админку удалось запустить только так:

```
 rewrite ^/cp/(.*)$ /cp/index.php$query_string last;
```

На фронте все работает, а в админке js, img, css 404, но в папке они есть.
Запросы в админке такого характера /cp/faq/list/0.htm

Answer (score 1):

Такая задача решается директивой [try_files](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), но не rewrite-ами.

```
location / {
    root        /var/site;
    try_files   $uri$is_args$args $uri $uri/index.html index.php$is_args$args;
}
location /admin/ {
    root        /var/site/cp;
    try_files   $uri$is_args$args $uri $uri/index.html index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
    ...
}
```