# upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx

Помогите устранить проблему пожалуйста.
Все работало до недавнего времени и вдруг стало выдавать в логах

> 2015/05/15 09:48:32 [error] 24053#0: *1800 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.85.159.254, server: technikaonline.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/www/php-fpm/technikaonline.sock:", host: "technikaonline.ru"

При этом сайт в хроме работает, в других браузерах отдает 502!

```html
#user 'technikaonline' virtual host 'technikaonline.ru' configuration file
server {
    listen 188.120.225.108:80;
    server_name technikaonline.ru www.technikaonline.ru;
    charset off;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.html index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/technikaonline/data/www/technikaonline.ru;
    ssi on;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/technikaonline.ru.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/technikaonline.ru.error.log notice;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

 # Cache static files such as images, styles and scripts
location ~ /\. { deny all; log_not_found off; access_log off; } 
        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

        location ~*  \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                expires 365d;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

location / {
  index index.php;

  # serve static files directly
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    access_log        off;
    expires           30d;

    break;
  }

  ### MAIN REWRITE - This will ignore directories
  if (!-d $request_filename) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php$query_string last;
  }
 if (!-d $request_filename) {
  rewrite ^/cp/(.*)$ /cp/index.php$query_string last;
  }

}


       # PHP FPM
  location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/technikaonline.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        ####try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;     
    }
}
```

Рабочий конфиг получился такой, в том числе решает проблемы поста [Nginx rule for Custom CMS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419797/nginx-rule-for-custom-cms/419800#419800)

```
#user 'technikaonline' virtual host 'technikaonline.ru' configuration file
server {
        listen 188.120.225.108:80;
        server_name technikaonline.ru www.technikaonline.ru;
        root $root_path;
        set $root_path /var/www/technikaonline/data/www/technikaonline.ru;
ssi on;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/technikaonline.ru.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/technikaonline.ru.error.log notice;
        index index.php;
        client_max_body_size 30M;
        location / {
                root $root_path;
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
                }
        }
        location /cp/ {
               # root $root_path/cp;
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /cp/index.php?q=$1 last;
                }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/technikaonline.sock;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 10240k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 10240k;
                fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;
        }

        location ~*  \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                expires 365d;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        }
}
```

Comment: Однако получилось переписать конфиг.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увеличь значения по настройкам размера и количества буферов fastcgi

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 10240k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 10240k;
```